# How to create a custom benefit

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have created a custom benefit/action for a promotion. When user applies the promo, nothing happens. There are no errors when i check in debug. The code is hit though.

```
public void Execute(IRuleExecutionContext context)
{
    .....code
    ......
   ApplyDiscountPercentForLineItems(commerceContext,  validCartLineItems, discountPercent, 
  awardingBlockName);
}

public static void ApplyDiscountPercentForLineItems(CommerceContext commerceContext, 
                     List<CartLineItem> validCartLineItems, decimal discountPercent, 
                     string awardingBlockName)
{
   var cart = (commerceContext.Objects.OfType<Cart>()).FirstOrDefault();
   var totals = (commerceContext.Objects.OfType<CartTotals>()).FirstOrDefault();

   var model = commerceContext.Objects.OfType<PropertiesModel>().FirstOrDefault();

   foreach (var line in validCartLineItems)
   {
     var discount = commerceContext.GetPolicy<KnownCartAdjustmentTypesPolicy>().Discount;
     var d = discountPercent;

     if (commerceContext.GetPolicy<GlobalPricingPolicy>().ShouldRoundPriceCalc)
     {
       d = decimal.Round(d, commerceContext.GetPolicy<GlobalPricingPolicy>().RoundDigits,
           commerceContext.GetPolicy<GlobalPricingPolicy>().MidPointRoundUp ? 
           MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero : MidpointRounding.ToEven);
     }

    decimal amount;    
    var currentAmount = totals.Lines[line.Id].SubTotal.Amount;    
    amount = currentAmount - (currentAmount * d / 100);
    amount = amount * decimal.MinusOne;
    totals.Lines[line.Id].SubTotal.Amount += amount;

    var item = new CartLineLevelAwardedAdjustment
    {
      Name = (string)model.GetPropertyValue("PromotionText"),
      DisplayName = (string)model.GetPropertyValue("PromotionCartText"),
      Adjustment = new Money(commerceContext.CurrentCurrency(), amount),
      AdjustmentType = discount,
      IsTaxable = false,
      AwardingBlock = awardingBlockName,
      IncludeInGrandTotal = true
    };

   line.Adjustments.Add(item);

   line.GetComponent<MessagesComponent>().AddMessage(
   commerceContext.GetPolicy<KnownMessageCodePolicy>().Promotions, 
   $"PromotionApplied: {model.GetPropertyValue("PromotionId")}");
 }           
}
```

Comment: What version are you using? I'm on 9.0.2 version and it doesn't have CartLineItem, but has CartLineComponent. Could you also check that validCartLineItems that you pass to a method is an actual data and you are not creating a new collection of items, that is not connected with context cart.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue previously and it was because by my custom benefit was implementing `IAction` and not `ICartLineAction`.

As part of the benefit resolution process the `IDiscoverPromotionsPipeline` is executed and it contains the `FilterPromotionsByBenefitTypeBlock`, which excludes any benefits that dont implement `ICartLineAction`.